# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to double

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

OK, so this code used to work until my friend decided to change the Firebase structure and now it doesn't work. Even now, if I change the code

Here's the error code :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: mapp.com.sg.notymeclient, PID: 26480
                  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to double
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaB(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzc(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzb(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzb(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zze(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaG(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zze(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzb(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                      at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:151)
                      at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:140)
                      at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:183)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6062)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6095)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5277)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5153)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2061)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1445)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1408)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:580)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3374)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3183)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3627)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17945)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17945)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17945)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17945)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17945)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                      at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:131)
                      at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                      at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1364)
                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:846)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17945)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                      at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1193)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17945)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17945)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
```

and here's my main code :

```
mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("users")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .child("sent");


        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_task);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mAdapter = new TaskAdapter(Task_GSON.class,R.layout.task_list_ui,TaskViewHolder.class,mRef);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);




        mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            int index = 0 ;
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot eachTask : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    task.add(new Task_GSON());
                    for(DataSnapshot data : eachTask.getChildren()){
                        String dataString = data.getValue().toString();
                        switch (data.getKey()){
                            case "taskTitle":
                                task.get(index).setTaskTitle(dataString);
                                break;
                            case "taskDescription":
                                task.get(index).setTaskDescription(dataString);
                                break;
                            case "sendBy":
                                task.get(index).setSendBy(dataString);
                                break;
                            case "recieveBy":
                                task.get(index).setRecieveBy(dataString);
                                break;
                            case "locationLong":
                                task.get(index).setLocationLong( Double.parseDouble(dataString) );
                                break;
                            case "locationLat":
                                task.get(index).setLocationLat( Double.parseDouble(dataString) );
                                break;
                            case "locationName":
                                task.get(index).setLocationName(dataString);
                                break;
                            case "status":
                                task.get(index).setStatus(Integer.parseInt(dataString));
                                break;
                            case "time":
                                task.get(index).setTime(Long.parseLong(dataString));
                                break;

                        }
                    }
                    index++;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

and here's my viewholder code :

```
public class TaskViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView textViewTitle;
    TextView textViewDescription;
    TextView textViewTime;
    TextView textViewTaskAssign;
    public TaskViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
        textViewDescription = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_task_description);
        textViewTime = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_time);
        textViewTaskAssign = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_task_assign);
    }
}
```

and here's my adapter codes:

```
public class TaskAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Task_GSON,TaskViewHolder> {
    public TaskAdapter(Class<Task_GSON> modelClass, int modelLayout, Class<TaskViewHolder> viewHolderClass, DatabaseReference ref) {
        super(modelClass, modelLayout, viewHolderClass, ref);
    }

    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(TaskViewHolder viewHolder, Task_GSON model, int position) {
        if(model != null){
            viewHolder.textViewDescription.setText(model.getTaskDescription());
            viewHolder.textViewTitle.setText(model.getTaskTitle());
            android.text.format.DateFormat df = new android.text.format.DateFormat();
            String reminderDate = df.format("dd/MM/yy hh:mm a" , model.getTime()).toString();
            viewHolder.textViewTime.setText(reminderDate);
            viewHolder.textViewTaskAssign.setText("send to:" +model.getRecieveBy());
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my database structure:

[image]

I couldn't find the error and the stacktrace doesn't help as it didn't pin point the code that mess up.

**------UPDATE 1--------**

ok so  I was curious if my code can actually view the data or not and i made a few tested myself
so first of i tried changing the database structure to something like this
[image]
**AND IT WORKED**
so i was curious and i tried another dataset but this time changing the parrent **member** to **user** like so

[image: change member to user]

**and it doesn't work**
so my hypothesis is that somehow either firebase adapter hates the word **user** or my code is doing something to firebase adapter to hate the word **user** as the original parent takes **users**

Comment: It´s hard to follow your code, The `Query` with `.child("sent")` key is not the same as your picture

Comment: Hi @Annonymous177, I think this is not correct `mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("users")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .child("sent");` In your image, the last parameters are ids and 'sent' is not there. That is correct?

Comment: woops wrong picture sorry i will edit it

Comment: You try to show your data to recylerview ? am i right?

Comment: @AmeerHamza yeah i am using firebase recycler adapter but if all else fails i will my own adapter

Comment: It's showing `Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to double`. So this should narrow down the search to the two `Double.parseDouble(dataString)` calls. Can you put in some logs to see the value of `dataString` before it's getting parsed?

Comment: ok it is weird, so I was just gonna test it with a different type of data set to see if it is my codes problem for not being able to view the data or it is something else cause i doubt that my database is wrong so i created a new dataset in the same database mimicking it but just changing the parrent from user to member and it worked. How is that possible.

Comment: @AL ya i log it the data is normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my data in my firebase was a string instead of a double for the locationLong and locationLat as evident as the 2 quotation marks in the data.

So the moral of the story here is check your variables

Thanks for all the helps in the comment section

[image: data structure]

Answer (score 0):

Here is code snapshot how i done

```
     recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_Recylerivew_);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        //DataBase raf
        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference();
        myRef.keepSynced(true);


        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Student,myViewHolader> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Student, myViewHolader>(


                Student.class,android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,myViewHolader.class,myRef
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(myViewHolader viewHolder, Student model, int position) {


                viewHolder.myTextView.setText(model.getName());

            }
        };

recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and my viewholder.java

```
 public static class myViewHolader extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView myTextView;


        public myViewHolader(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            myTextView= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        }
}
```

if you want to get full code [here is link](https://github.com/ameerhamza6733/FirebaseReadAndWriteDemo/blob/ac7ae3ec831cea03471415ce7c04a466f3094e71/app/src/main/java/com/example/ameerhamza/firebabseyoutubetest/MainActivity.java) to my github and if you want [video tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHFnPDoD_Ug)  is link to my channel

Comment: i have found the solution already, it is because my firebase data for longitude and latitude is in string format and my class for the firebase adapter for the data for longitude and latitude is double not string,Thanks for the help thou ;)