# Android Firebase, Unable to fetch the data

Tags: android, mysql, json, database, firebase

I created a family tree application on java and mysql database. Now I am testing an android app for the same. So I converted my mysql database file to JSON format and uploaded it to firebase. When I am inserting records on it, it is working perfectly fine but when I try to fetch the data it is showing the error:

com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to int
                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source:180)

What should be the problem? I tried deleting the data from the database which I uploaded through JSON file and then inserted records directly from app into database and fetch them, it worked fine but when I am adding record from JSON file only then It is creating problem.

here is the code from the app for fetching data:

```
public void clicked(){
    mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {


        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<Family> FamilyList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot adSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Family f = adSnapshot.getValue(Family.class);
                FamilyList.add(f);
               // adsList.add(adSnapshot.getValue(Family.class));
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Total Records: "+FamilyList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Family Model Class:

```
public class Family {

int id;
String name;
String fatherName;
int fid;
String city;
String state;

public Family(int id, String name, String fatherName, int fid, String city, String state) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.fatherName = fatherName;
    this.fid = fid;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
}

public Family()
{

}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getFatherName() {
    return fatherName;
}

public void setFatherName(String fatherName) {
    this.fatherName = fatherName;
}

public int getFid() {
    return fid;
}

public void setFid(int fid) {
    this.fid = fid;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}
}
```

Here is the JSON Record Sample
[image: Here is the JSON Record Sample]

It is the records which I entered through App
[image: It is the records which I entered through App]

I think the converted JSON treated id and fid as String, while in mySQL they are int. (am I correct?)

Tell me if any other code is needed.

Comment: SHow us both your Family class and your database structure please?

Comment: yes, converted JSON treated id and fid as String and in your model you store it in int.

Comment: please try to change datatype of your id and fid as a string in model or you need to casting.

Comment: is there any way to convert mysql to json without affecting the data structure? I converted this by csvjson.com

Comment: I think, you should change our model datatype of id and fid as string and try to run your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem relies on here

```
Family f = adSnapshot.getValue(Family.class);
```

you are trying to get data in an inappropriate type.

You should correct this by checking Family.class and check if the values there are the same as they are in your database structure in firebase, it will be helpful if you put your database structure here, or some images.

Check if for example in Family.class you have in your variable types the same as they are in firebase, with the same name also.

So for example if in firebase there is an string called name you should have in your constructor inside Family.class the same type and name.

```
String name;
```

and in Firebase your json key should be name too.

For instance, check this

[image]

your Family class for example should have the variables with the same name and type as your database.

[image]

Also check, if the value in firebase has "" is an String type and in your POJO you should have a variable with the type String for what you are trying to access, but if the value dosnt have "" it should be a long , int, double or any type of number.

EDIT: check this structure

[image]

It has all the values types as String, but in your Family.class you have the values right for this type of structure.

[image]

you should change your database at firebase so all your types matches with the ones in your Family.class, either way it won't fetch your values

Note: if you want to fetch all your values like they are at the first image, just change in Family.class from this:

```
int id;
String name;
String fatherName;
int fid;
String city;
String state;
```

to this:

```
String id;
String name;
String fatherName;
String fid;
String city;
String state;
```

Also change your constructor types and everything to match all Strings

The thing is that firebase creates unique IDs for each element in your database structure, and the types imported from your MySQL database are not the same as the firebase ones, I suggest you to either change your Family.class variable types as I mentioned above, or replicate your MySQL database with firebase and the same variable types.

Comment: added data structure of the db. please have a look. I think, uploaded JSON is treating id and fid as int?

Comment: hi @PankajChaudhary , you are getting errors because the first entry below the 0 tree have all the types as String, but at your second entry with the userID as the father it has all the values right

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked.. didn't notice it before.. thanks

Comment: Glad it helped , any other qustion feel free to ask, we are here to help !

Comment: Yes of course! One more thing, If I want the values as int! is there any way to convert sql to json which did not affect the existing data structure. I converted this by csvjson.com

Comment: at that page after you paste your sql data, in the VALUE part of it change it to your needs, and it will convert that sql data into json with the values you pass , the thing is that that converter converts all the values as Strings, maybe in your sql datbase all the values were with type String

Comment: No, the id and fid is int in my sql database. The records are more in numbers, so changing every record is time consuming. I think changing them all to string is only way left?

Comment: i mean, you can still use string as all your value types in your Family.class , and in firebase it will work , but for best practices is better to have your database structured as the second image

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have a variable of integer datatype in your model but you are returning String from Firebase... either convert your variable to string or return  integer from firebase.... 
Both model and Firebase variable should be of a same data type.

Comment: hi, check my answer

Comment: added data structure of the db. please have a look. I think, uploaded JSON is treating id and fid as int?

Comment: @PankajChaudhary in the first tree you have both id & Fid as String.... take a advice..... convert all datatype to string .......and then try to retrieve data

Comment: @PankajChaudhary .  :)

Answer (score 0):

As per your below error:-

com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to int at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source:180)

I think, **you need to check somewhere you tried to store value in int which is store in firebase in string.**

So first check it and if necessary to cast then **casting your value using Integer.parseInt** or **Integer.valueof**

for example,

```
Integer.valueOf(dataSnapShot.getValue());
```

or

```
Integer.parseInt(dataSnapShot.getValue());
```

**For more understanding this you can also refer stack overflow's below links:**

[Firebase DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552348/firebase-databaseexception-failed-to-convert-value-of-type-java-lang-long-to-st)

[com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41698380/com-google-firebase-database-databaseexception-failed-to-convert-a-value-of-typ)

[Firebase android error "Failed to convert value of type "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44098562/firebase-android-error-failed-to-convert-value-of-type?rq=1)

Comment: added data structure of the db. please have a look. I think, uploaded JSON is treating id and fid as int?